# C++ `for` loops iterate only once when it should be multiple

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector

I'm trying to go a brute-force route in C++ to solve LeetCode's apparently most popular problem, the "Two Sum" problem, as described at the 0:32 marker in this video: https://youtu.be/KLlXCFG5TnA?t=32. Essentially, I need to iterate through each possible combination of 2-digit sums in the vector until I reach some desired target number. I then return the 2 indices of the numbers whose values combine to equal the target number.

My code worked for the first 17 test cases LeetCode threw at it. But for the test case below, the `for` loops are only iterating once, despite the iterator never reaching their respective limits (`nums.size()-2` and `nums.size()-1`).

I step through the debugger slowly but am lost as to why the code is breaking out of the `for` loops "early."

**Solution.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> twoSum(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        vector<int> result_vector;
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 2; i++) { // this for loop [undesirably] only iterates once
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.size() - 1; j++) { // this for loop also [undesirably] only iterates once
                if (nums.at(i) + nums.at(j) == target) {
                    result_vector.push_back(i);
                    result_vector.push_back(j);
                }
            }
        }
        if (result_vector.size() == 0) {
            result_vector.push_back(-1);
            result_vector.push_back(-1);
            cout << "No solution found.";
        }
        return result_vector;
    }
};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include "Solution.h"

int main()
{
    Solution sol;

    vector<int> vect{3, 2, 4};
    int target = 6;

    sol.twoSum(vect, target);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `3 - 2 == 1`, that means the only `i` that works is `0` as `1` is not less than `1`.

Comment: _"... despite the iterator never reaching their respective limits..."_ is mistaken.

Comment: ha...woops. For some reason I remembered from my school days needing to always add a `-1` in each `for` loop's end condition to avoid out-of-bounds errors. I changed `nums.size()-2` to `nums.size()-1` and `nums.size()-1` to `nums.size()`. Thank you

Comment: The vector being passed as size of `3`, and the outer for loop iterates from `0` to less than that size minus two.     That is one iteration of the outer loop.  Similarly, the first iteration of the inner loop will run from `j = 1` until `j` is less than the size minus 1 (i.e. from 1 to 1).   Again that is one iteration.   Unless you explain WHY you expect/need those loops to both iterate more than once, nobody can help you - from the code you have supplied the EXPECTED behaviour is exactly what you consider undesirable.

Comment: I've already been helped. I linked to a video explaining the problem and why I'd like to iterate more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vector `vect` passed to the function as an argument

```
vector<int> vect{3, 2, 4};
```

has three elements.

So within the function the outer loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 2; i++) {
```

has only one iteration due to the condition

```
i < nums.size() - 2
```

that is equivalent to

```
i < 3 - 2
```

Pay attention to that you shall not use the type int as the type of index. Otherwise this loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.size() - 2; i++) {
```

can invoke undefined behavior when an empty vector is passed to the function because in this case `i` can be always less than `nums.size() - 2` or `nums.size() - 1` due to the usual arithmetic conversions.

Your program can look for example the following way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

struct Solution 
{
    typedef std::vector<int>::size_type size_type;
    
    std::vector<std::pair<size_type, size_type>> 
    operator ()( const std::vector<int> &v, int target ) 
    {
        std::vector<std::pair<size_type, size_type>> result;
        
        
        for ( size_type i = 1; i < v.size(); i++ )
        {
            for ( size_type j = i; j < v.size(); j++ )
            {
                if ( v[j] + v[i-1] == target )
                {
                    result.push_back( { i - 1, j } );
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 3, 2, 4 };
    int target = 6;
    
    auto result = Solution()( v, target );
    
    for ( const auto &p : result )
    {
        std::cout << "( " << p.first << ", " << p.second << " ) ";
    }
    
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
( 1, 2 )
```